# Defining a const with error ESLint: Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'. (prefer-rest-params)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I can't resolve this, please help me.

```
 const params =
        arguments.length > 3 && arguments[3] !== undefined
          ? arguments[3]
          : null;
```

The problem is with arguments[3] 
ESLint says: Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'. (prefer-rest-params)

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params

Comment: yes @epascarello but i don't know how apply it in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your function looks like where this is happening, but I'll give you an example of the `rest params` ESLint is talking about with the tiny snippet of code you provided:

```js
function foo( ...args ) {
  console.log( args );
  const params =
          args.length > 3 && args[3] !== undefined
            ? args[3]
            : null;

  console.log( params );
}

foo( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

So `...args` is an array of all arguments passed on in the function call that you have not set as a parameter. Any parameter you do have, goes in front of `...args`. (Note that you can call this anything you want, such as `...rest`.) The reason this might be preferred over **arguments** is because you cannot use any Array methods on it, while on the rest params you can.